# Installing win 7 on new laptop with emmc

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, hard-drive, partitioning, drivers

I am trying to install 32-bit win 7 on a HP Stream c004tu that comes with a Samsung MBG4C eMmc harddrive, on win 8.1.

I can get up to booting the installation usb by changing bios settings, but after clicking 'install now' I get the dreaded 'load drivers' error message. After some research, I tried to get around it by changing usb ports and using different isos (the non-refresh media), but it didn't work. When I do diskpart->list disk, it says there are no disks.

I think [this](http://www.sevenforums.com/installation-setup/344733-how-install-window-7-ssd-emmc.html) perhaps is a similar problem to mine and he solved it by adding emmc drivers to the bootable installation, presumably via [this method.](http://forums.anandtech.com/showpost.php?s=d399c0c6aafcfdba81542d74441d52e3&p=34187066&postcount=4)

The problem is I cannot find drivers for my emmc harddisk, and samsung's contact us link fails when I submit.

Looking in device manager, my current emmc driver is by microsoft but i am using 64-bit win 8 so I didn't think that would help. Help?